# Backbone REST request to add users to project?

Tags: codeigniter, rest, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm designing an application following REST specification but I'm unsure how to structure the following.

I have projects, which follow the basic CRUD process.  I also have users which also follow a basic CRUD process.  However I have an operation of adding users to a project and I'm not sure how to make the request.

A user can have multiple projects, so I'm thinking it should be some kind of PUT request, but the project id is not really part of the user model.

```
PUT /users/project/3
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though the User can have many Projects and a Project can have many Users. In that case managing that relationship is best done through a join table that you could name something like Participants which would have a user_id and a project_id.

Then you can choose whether to manage Participants through a User or through a Project. To me it would make sense to manage your Projects Participants, and because you are creating a new Participant it is a POST.

```
POST /projects/:project_id/participants
```

The payload would contain the user_id.

Comment: okay, I think this is the piece I was missing, that the the association itself between projects/users is a POST request on it's own.  I will have to modify my REST handler in codeigniter but this will solve a lot of problems for me, by default for a `POST /projects` call i have a `index_post()` function in the projects controller, now I can have a `user_post()` handler there as well, which makes a lot of sense from a design point of view and also even lets me have a user controller with a `project_post()` handler if I wanted to.

Answer (score 1):

If project id is not part of the user model, then that implies an array of user ids is part of the project model ... right?  So I think this would be appropriate to add a user to a project:

```
PUT /projects/(projectid)/users/(userid)
```

However, maybe you don't need to support those URLs if they're not needed by the consumers of the service (ie, Backbone); maybe you just want a single endpoint to update projects:

```
PUT /projects/(projectid)
```

and your Ajax post call would include a list of users as part of the "update this project" request.

You might want to use either form of the URL from Backbone, depending on the UI.  The first form of the URL is really only useful for requests like "add user x to project y" (say when an admin clicks clicks "add this user to the current project", or whatever).

The second form of the URL is what you might use for updating a project wholesale, which could include the list of users, name of the project, etc; that is the "edit project" view.

```
var ProjectModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "project_name": "",
        "users: [0]
    },

    urlRoot: "/myrestapi/projects",

    url: function() {
        return this.urlRoot + "/" + this.cid;
    }
});
```

A Backbone *save* request on this model would trigger a (POST? PUT?) to the URL:

```
/myrestapi/projects/(cid)
```

With the post data representing the model state of the project:

```
{ "project_name": "foo", "users": [15, 18, 42] }
```

It's then up to your REST service to trigger the updates to your server's data store ...

Comment: okay, that makes sense, but this is where I get a little confused.  If I'm already using put /projects/(projectid) to update project attributes, then this seems like a separate process to me.  Or does that mean that my PUT function should have logic for different cases based on how the URL is formed or what parameters it receives?

Comment: Also, how would I send this type of request using backbone.js?  I'm not really updating the user or project models here.  If anything I have a project with a list of users, so it's more like a POST request for a user, since I need to add that user to the collection - only thing is user already exists in db, they are just being added to the project.

Comment: @Rob I think the *PUT* function could have different logic depending on the URL; it really depends whether you want to support a full REST API, or just those URLs that are really needed by the Backbone application.  Please see my update for an example.

Comment: From Backbone, you're free to structure it in different ways;  you could have a separate **users_projects** model corresponding to a similar many-to-many table in your database.  You could get fancy and use a nested model inside the *user* model.  Or you could just skip the model and do a raw Ajax POST/PUT back to your REST service.